# UICollectionView lag/slow in scrolling SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

hello I am displaying two images in my `CollectionView` dynamically. I am using `sd_webImage` to display the images. The problem is there is lag coming while scrolling the cells. I have googled it and try some solution but still no luck.

This is how I am showing the images

```
        cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(profileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder_profile_image"))

            cell.productImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(productImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder_product_image"))
```

I have tried this also

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {


            let  profileImageUrl = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.section)"] as?NSDictionary)!["User"] as?NSDictionary)!["profile_image"] as?NSString)

            let productImageUrl = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Trip"] as?NSDictionary)!["product_image_path"] as?NSString)! as String

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(profileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder_profile_image"))

                cell.productImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(productImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder_product_image"))
}
}
```

but still showing lag

Answer (score 0):

Use [Time Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) Instrument to detect where is the exact problem.

Comment: I don't know how to use that